# Captcha showing on post, post failing after captcha verification

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

For some unknown reason we are getting a captcha on every feed post using the following code:

**feed**

Publishing to the stream is easy, as all the fields are optional. Just specify
what you need, and leave the rest out.

```
<script>
var publish = {
  method: 'feed',
  message: '',
  name: 'test name',
  caption: 'test caption',
  description: 'test description',
  link: 'http://fb.mylist.com/ws/uipr?uiid=fdec6c79-d0b6-7091-c3db-b5ec6386b46c&lid=b6cb3994-fa91-4548-b1f7-f3d945e29de4',
  picture: 'http://mylist3.vo.msecnd.net/26381278/original/8e7a33d0-06f4-3503-b07d-31c16bb4ab0a.img'
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
</script>
```

We have no idea why we are getting the captcha.  In addition, when the user satisfies the captcha the post is not successful.  Any idea why we are getting the captcha and the post is not working after the captcha?

Answer (score 1):

This has been documented in the Bugs section of the Facebook Developers site. Please report it there so we can help bring it to their attention. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/347441388626378

Answer (score 0):

If facebook always shows a captcha it suspects (either correctly or incorrectly) that you are spamming. Sometimes, as an extra anti-spam measure, it will not process your request even if you enter the captcha correctly. I have experienced this with the send message dialog. Think about why Facebook thinks you are spamming and adjust your app or use of the app accordingly.